# Users management - allow local installation

Tags: users, user-management

I'm building a workstation that will be used by different users.
I don't want to make them sudoers but I'd like for them to be able to install anything they within their account (no system wide installations).
I read about chroot and debootstrap but that would be to heavy, now I came across to LXC and FreeBSD jails, but I'm still not sure about it.

What's the best way to do this right?

Comment: Depends what they will be installing. AppImages are trivial to install per-user, Debs are not.

Comment: @user535733 very likely I'd need to install deb packags

Comment: Will users need different kernels? By 'Workstation', one assumes you mean a Desktop with a GUI? Will each user want to option to install different *versions* of, say, one application? Or is the same version for everybody acceptable?

Comment: How complex and admin-heavy a solution are you willing to accept? From your description, seems like you don't want to admin (like installing packages for others) much at all. Is that right? Also, what's your skill level?

Comment: @user535733 let's just say I'm not the IT guy, this is a workstation I'm going to use myself as a user together with about ten other colleagues of mine. I offered to manage the machine because I'm interested in the topic, but that's not my primary job. Finally I don't want the solution to be admin-heavy, I'm willing to step in when needed but not for every software installation. LXC seem overcomplicated for my skills (I graduated last year), I think I'm going to use linuxbrew for now, but I'm still open to suggestions.